# Navbar Bootstrap 4 collapse já automatico

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estou copiando EXATAMENTE qualquer modelo de navbar que encontrei na nova documentação do bootstrap 4 que estou a utilizar nos meus projetos.

Só que, ele já vem "collapsado" digamos assim.

Existe alguma função em javascript que eu possa colocar para que ele não "collaspse" automaticamente.

Segue o menu que copiei do bootstrap 4: https://jsfiddle.net/7pq9zoaL/

Esse é o layout que estou fazendo: https://jsfiddle.net/yxwzwq7e/ (uma dashboard simples)

Comment: Rafael, edita a pergunta com o código  de exemplo? você pode usar o Bootstrap CND(https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bootstrap-cdn) para o fiddle.

Comment: Atualizei, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, na div `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">` consta a classe `collapse` que justamente "colide" a sua nav. Basta remover, ficando assim  `<div class="navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">`, segue exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Ou você pode manter a classe `collapse` e executar a função `toggle()` do Jquery após o load da sua página com o seguinte código do Jquery `$("#nav-content").toggle();`, segue exemplo:

```js
$("#nav-content").toggle();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav-content">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```